# Organizing CakePHP code

Tags: php, cakephp, refactoring

I'm having a problem understanding the difference between component, utility and behavior.
I read the Cookbook, but it helped me only partly.

For example – I want to resize/crop images on upload. 
I will use a number of different forms related to different models and controllers/actions.

Obviously I need to write a class with **scale**, **resize**, **saveImage** and other helpful methods.
I also need the ability to use this methods from different places.

My question is – where is the right place to put this code? And can someone provide me some simple examples about core difference between component, utility and behavior? Because for me components and utilities looks very similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Behaviors** are packages of logic that apply to *Models*.
- **Components** are packages of logic that apply to *Controllers*.
- **Utilities** are general libraries that don't necessarily apply to any one specific part of MVC.

The major difference between Utilities and Behaviors/Components is that *Utility classes don't extend a core MVC class, and thus don't automatically receive hooks into their parent class's request cycle*. For example, in a Component, you could implement a `beforeRender()` function that would get called before the controller renders its layout/views, automatically, every time that controller gets called.

Also, Utility classes must be instantiated and assigned to a variable before use: `$myUtil = new MyUtility(); $myUtil->blah()` -- Behaviors/Components/Helpers get instantiated when they're loaded into a class and can be referenced with `$this->MyComponent->blah()`.

In your case, the image manipulation logic would most likely belong in either a Component or a Utility class, and you can choose to implement it either way. Personally, I would go with writing a Component since you're unlikely to utilize the image manipulation logic outside of your Controllers.

**Edit**: You might also consider finding and using an existing component that someone has already written, for example I found [ImageTool](https://github.com/raitisg/CakePHP-ImageTool-Component), [Image Resizer](https://github.com/renobrant/Image-Resizer-Component-for-CakePHP2), [Image Upload & Resizer](https://github.com/hunzinker/CakePHP-Image-Upload---Resize-Component), and [Thumbnail](https://github.com/tute/Thumbnail-component-for-CakePHP) in about 2 minutes of Google searching.

Comment: I'll take a look at these components. But first of all I want to understand how it works and learn how to create similar functionality. :) Your answer was very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Behaviors are where you put code that should be reused across multiple models
Components are where you place code that will be used across multiple controllers
and Helpers are where you place code that will be used across multiple views

That's the basic breakdown.

Since Controllers are responsible for application logic, It seems that it makes the most sense for you to build your uploader/scaler into a component.

If you needed to modify how data is accessed, or returned from the database, that would be a behavior (as it affects the model layer)

If you needed to create some reusable code for generating HTML or some type of view output, that would be a helper.

For your example of uploading, scaling and resizing images. I would make that into a component. For instance I have a component called UploadComponent.php that uploads, saves, and creates thumbnail images.

I add this component to my controllers by doing:

```
 var components = array('Upload');
```

And then I can use it in my controller by doing the following:

```
$this->Upload->createThumbnail(200, 200);
```

The details of how you implement your components are up to you, obviously.

Hope that helps.